# How can I tell if a function is a class?

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm writing a React component that takes a `renderer` property. In general, this is a function that takes in an object of arguments and returns another React component. However, I would like for users of my component to be able to pass in a React component class instead. I would then internally wrap that class in a function:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { renderer } = this.props;

        const renderFn = (renderer.isAComponentClass())
            ? (props => <renderer {...props} />)
            : renderer;

        return <div>{ renderFn(someArgs) }</div>;
    }
}
```

Of course, in JavaScript, a class is also a function. How can I check whether `renderer` is a class? I am using Babel 6.

I am aware that I could simple return `<renderer {...someArgs} />`. I would rather not do this if I can avoid it, because this unnecessarily bloats the component tree.

Comment: What if someone is using a Babel-compiled version of a class? Then no matter what they are both just `function` at that point. You'd be better off accepting two separate parameters.

Comment: In either case, they are functions (i.e. `typeof thing === 'function'`). However, that does not *necessarily* mean that there is no way to differentiate them. If there verifiably is no way, then that would be an answer.

Comment: Well, if the `fn` was a component class, then the `fn.prototype` should contain base class component methods so you could test for the existence of those.  If it was just a factory function, the `fn.prototype` would not contain the component methods.

Comment: *"to be able to pass in a React component class instead"* You can check wether `renderer.prototype && renderer.prototype instanceof React.Component`.

Comment: @FelixKling `renderer.prototype &&` is not necessary. Not really effective, since this won't work even if a dev thinks that it's a valid component - e.g. for decorated class.

Comment: @estus: You are right. I was just thinking that arrow functions don't have a `prototype` property and so I added that for no reason.

Comment: @FelixKling Yep, they don't. The recipe requires the opposite, to check this for right-hand side of instanceof, which is not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to detect native classes with regular expression - as long as they don't implement `toString` method that will change their representation as a string.

It is not possible to detect if a function is a class due to the fact that classes don't differ from functions in transpiled code. This is a good reason to not even try to distinguish them programmatically.

It is possible to check if `React.Component` is the ancestor of a function/class with

```
renderer.prototype instanceof React.Component
```

Since this puts unnecessary restriction, a better option is to duck test it, like

```
renderer.prototype && ['render', 'setState', ...]
  .map(methodName => typeof renderer.prototype[methodName])
  .every(methodType => methodType === 'function')
```

However, none of these checks are accurate. `prototype` property can be messed up in some cases, e.g. when a class is decorated. The only way to certainly know that a class is a component is to instantiate it first.

And API would be cleaner if renderer function and component could never be confused, for instance separate `renderer` and `rendererComponent` properties.